# Oracle verify function 12c - string distance

Tags: oracle, passwords

The oracle verify function includes a setting which checks for the distance of the last passsword. ora12c_verify_function:

```
   -- Check if the password differs from the previous password by at least
   -- 3 characters
   IF old_password IS NOT NULL THEN
     differ := string_distance(old_password, password);
     IF differ < 3 THEN
        raise_application_error(-20010, 'Password should differ from the ' 
                                || 'old password by at least 3 characters');
     END IF;
   END IF ;

   RETURN(TRUE);
END;
```

Why it is possible to change the password with only one different character?

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> ALTER USER TEST PROFILE DEFAULT;
SQL> ALTER PROFILE default LIMIT PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION ora12c_verify_function;

SQL> alter user test identified by "123456789_abc!";

User altered.

SQL> alter user test identified by "123456789_abc!";
alter user test identified by "123456789_abc!"
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28007: the password cannot be reused


SQL> alter user test identified by "123456789_abcd!";

User altered.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the soultion on Oracle Support Doc [ID 816932.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=270177306904128&id=816932.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=13tu8kd6yc_4). The issue is related to the fact that the ALTER USER privilege does not require the user to know the old password, so consequently it will not check this old password when this privilege is used. Without the privilige the user needs to supply the old password with the REPLACE command.

```
ALTER USER SCOTT IDENTIFIED BY NEWPASSWORD REPLACE TIGER;
```